# Union of array inside array using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, promise, lodash

How can I union arrays inside an array using lodash?

For example:

> Input:
>
> ```
> var x = [ [1,2,3,4], [5,6,7], [], [8,9], [] ];
> ```
>
> Expected output:
>
> ```
> x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
> ```

Currently my code does the following:

```
return promise.map(someObjects, function (object)) {
    return anArrayOfElements();
}).then(function (arrayOfArrayElements) {
    // I tried to use union but it can apply only on two arrays
    _.union(arrayOfArrayElements);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `_.flatten`?

Comment: yep worked just now _.union(_.flatten(x))

Comment: Check out the example "Flatten an array of arrays" in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce. It does exactly what you want :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worked answer for me , all other answers worked but when i checked other post they simply used loadash. I dnt know what is the best syntax to use for all the answers provided in the post.
For now using the below method

```
_.uniq(_.flatten(x)); // x indicates arrayOfArrayObjects
// or, using chain
_(x).flatten().uniq().value();
```

Thanks everyone for their answers. :)

Answer (score 6):

Use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method to pass array values as arguments:

```
var union = _.union.apply(null, arrayOfArrayElements);
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/qe5n89dh/ ]

Comment: why are we passing null as parameter ?

Comment: Because we do not need to pass `this` (see. `apply` definition).

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution I can think of is to just use `concat`:

```
Array.prototype.concat.apply([], [ [1,2,3,4], [5,6,7],[], [8,9], []]);
```

Will produce...

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
```

Comment: `Concat` not remove duplicate items instead `lodash union`.

Comment: Ah, I missed that it should remove dupes.

Answer (score 1):

Just reduce it using the native function `reduce`

```
arr.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) { 
    return previousValue.concat(currentValue);
}, []);
```

This will apply the reduce callback function to each element of the array and reduce it for the use case you have shown.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce